# Font Size too big on LG device

Tags: android

I have a layout that fits perfectly on mdpi tablets.
However, when i run the application on my hdpi LG tablet, the font 
gets bigger than it supposed to be.

an example of how i scale my layout and set the textsize:

```
        int nameTvHeight = (int)ConvertDpToPix (heightScale  * 11);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,nameTvHeight);
        p2.Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;
        nameTv.LayoutParameters = p2;
        nameTv.TextSize = nameTvHeight;
        nameTv.SetIncludeFontPadding (false);
```

On the LG tablet, it looks like the fontsize is bigger than the height of the textview, so it gets cut off at the bottom. Can anyone point out the reasons and/or the solutions to this?

Also, the fontsize in the settings is set on normal, and the font itself is roboto like the default android typeface. The tablet has Android version 4.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, when i run the application on my hdpi LG tablet, the font
>   gets bigger than it supposed to be.

it is because you are already converting the text size value in `dp`, and `setTextSize` scales it again in `sp`. Call `setTextSize` this way

```
setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size);
```